# Где лямбда-выражение (объект-замыкание) хранит захваченные переменные?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

```
// C++11
#include <functional>
using fp = std::function<int()>;

fp f1(int i)
{
    i *= 100;
    return [i]() mutable { return i++; };
}

fp f2(int a, int b)
{
    return [a, b]() mutable { a++; b--; return a * b; };
}

int main()
{
    fp p;
    int i;

    p = f1(1);
    i = p();
    i = p();
    i = p();

    p = f2(3, 5);
    i = p();
    i = p();
    i = p();

    return 0;
}
```

Можно ли использовать то, что возвращают функции f1 и f2? Если да, то где хранятся объекты-замыкания с их захваченными переменными?

Answer (score 12):

"Лямбда функция" это некорректный термин, который может создать ложное впечатление о том как работает код.

Выражение `[i]() mutable { return i++; }` называется **лямбда-выражение** (lambda expression).
Результат лямбда-выражения - это **объект-замыкание** (closure object), который является функциональным объектом (имеет перегруженный `operator()`) и хранит в себе копию переменной `i`.
Тип объекта-замыкания - это анонимный класс, который выглядит примерно так:

```
class __closure {
public:
  __closure(const __closure&) = default;
  ~__closure() = default;

  int operator()();

private:
  __closure(unspecified arguments);
  __closure& operator=(const __closure&) = default;
  __closure() = delete;

  int i;
};
```

Как и любой другой функциональный объект, объект-замыкание можно положить в `std::function` соответствующего типа.

---

В случае если замыкания нет, у объекта-замыкания есть функция, преобразующая его в указатель на функцию:

```
class __closure {
  using signature = int();
  static int body();
public:
  int operator() { return body(); }
  operator signature*() { return &body; }
  ...
```

При этом он также называется "объект-замыкание" и его тип является классом.

Comment: А где хранится экземпляр класса __closure (объект-замыкание) создаваемый выражением `return [i]() mutable { return i++; };` ? В куче?

Comment: Но ведь при выходе из функции жизнь её локальных (размещаются в стеке и регистрах) переменных (в том числе и rvalue) заканчивается! Может быть, тогда преобразование к `std::function<int()>` перемещает объект-замыкание в кучу?

Comment: Сейчас бегло посмотрел реализацию std::function от Майкрософт - похоже, что так оно и есть!!!

Comment: @Андрей А где у вас есть такая "незаканчивающаяся" жизнь лямбды? Она возвращается из функций, сохраняется в локальной переменной, по выходе из `main()` уничтожается... С чего вы решили, что что-то перемещается в кучу?!

Comment: @Abyx, дело в том, что функции f1 и f2 возвращают не объекты-замыкания, а объекты типа `std::function`, которые использует копию объектов-замыкания в куче.

Comment: Условно говоря, "жизнь лямбды" заканчивается в деструкторе std::function в котором она убирается из кучи.

Comment: @Abyx, как вы считаете нужно ли в (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) исправить "Lambda functions" на "Lambda expressions"?

Answer (score 7):

Согласно стандарту C++ (5.1.2 Lambda expressions)

> 15 An entity is captured by copy if it is implicitly captured and the
>   capture-default is = or if it is explicitly captured with a capture
>   that is not of the form & identiﬁer or & identiﬁer initializer. For
>   each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is
>   declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members
>   is unspeciﬁed. The type of such a data member is the type of the
>   corresponding captured entity if the entity is not a reference to an
>   object, or the referenced type otherwise. [Note: If the captured
>   entity is a reference to a function, the corresponding data member is
>   also a reference to a function. —end note] A member of an anonymous
>   union shall not be captured by copy.

В этой функции

```
fp f(int i)
{
    i *= 100
    return [i]() mutable { return i++; };
}
```

при каждом ее вызове создается локальное лямбда-выражение, которая захватывает копированием параметр функции.

То есть возвращаемое лямбда-выражение будет иметь то значение переменной (параметра) `i`, которое та имела в момент вызова функции, так как значение этого параметра копируется в неименованный член данных соответствующего объекта лямбда-выражения.

Вы можете представить это следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using fp = std::function<int()>;

fp f(int i)
{
    i *= 100;

    struct A
    {
        A(int i) : i(i) {}
        int i;

        int operator ()() { return i++;  }
    };

    return A( i );
}

int main()
{
    fp p;
    int i;

    p = f(1);
    std::cout << ( i = p() ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ( i = p() ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ( i = p() ) << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы будет

```
100
101
102
```

Comment: @Андрей Что вы хотите этим сказать?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь выражение `return A( i );` выполняет создание объекта типа А в стеке, потом это каким-то образом приводится к `std::function<int()>` (я ещё не силён в STL). Но ведь, после выхода из функции это объект больше не существует! Или как?

Comment: @Андрей Мой пример функции по существу аналогичен вашему примеру функции. Класс std::function копирует в себя возвращаемый из функции функциональный объект, независимо, как он задан: либо в виде лямбда-выражения или в виде объекта явно определенного класса.

Comment: @Андрей Поъоже, вы изменили свой вопрос уже после появления ответов. Это плохая идея, так как вводит в заблуждение читающих вопрос и ответы.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду главный вопрос или вопрос в комментарии? Если главный вопрос, то это потому что где-то здесь в справке прочитал рекомендации по улучшению вопроса. Если вопрос в комментарии, то это потому-что я здесь ещё новичок и писал комментарий за несколько подходов (извиняюсь).

Comment: Видимо, аналогичен не в полной мере. А вопрос у меня как раз в нюансах.

Comment: @Андрей Если я не ошибаюсь, вы добавили еще одну функцию в вопрос. Я ответил на ваш вопрос, что создаются объекта лямбда-выражения, которые копируют в свои неименованные члены класса захваченные переменные, если переменные не имеют ссылочный тип. И показал в своем условном примере механизм этого процесса.

Comment: Хорошо, пусть захваченные переменные хранятся в объектах лямбда-выражений, но тогда следующий вопрос - где хранятся сами эти объекты лямбда-выражений. А вторую функцию я добавил для того, что бы показать что в переменную p они, вроде как, не могут перемещаться.

Comment: @Андрей Я же вам показал по аналогии с обычным классом, что такое лямбда-выражение. Что не понятно в моем примере? Лямбда выражение - это объект неименованного класса.

Answer (score 4):

Грубо упрощенно можно представить, что лямбда-функция внутренне превращается во что-то типа

```
class Lambda
{
    захваченные переменные

    type operator()(params) { ... };
```

а потом вызывается как

```
Lambda L;

L();
```

так что хранятся данные в полях (данных-членах) соответствующего класса.